# iOS Duplicated implementation --> Test failing

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

A lot of my tests are suddenly failing and I think it has something to do with this console output:

```
    objc[46098]: Class GGLClearcutWriter is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGLClearcutAccountData is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGLClearcutRequest is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGLClearcutLogger is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGLConfiguration is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGLConfigurationV2 is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GMRConfiguration is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGLBundleUtil is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGLContext is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGLHash is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGL_CLEARCUTClientanalyticsRoot is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGL_CLEARCUTLuser_nameventKeyValues is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[46098]: Class GGL_CLEARCUTActiveExperiments is implemented in both /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C0F9526-F930-43F6-AB6F-AADF1DB2C780/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/679F4B16-4677-43C8-B025-E582E2A8FF2A/AppName.app/AppName and /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-edmnkgnmwezwfqcqnznlsuagoizc/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/AppName/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameTests.xctest/AppNameTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I assume that GGL_* has something to to with Google which is coming from Google Analytics that is imported via cocoapods.

The tests pass on first run on a fresh simulator, but fail on the second or later run.

The app is running fine.
Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this says that both the app and the tests too are linking in the same categories.
This is unnecessary and may needlessly increase the size of the tests target

**BUT since both are the same in your case, it is harmless and I don't see how this would make tests fail**

Comment: I removed the google stuff and they are still failing